# Syntax errors and logic errors

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, logic

I have a problem with my syntax, but I am stuck on it for some reason, logic errors. Syntax problems on

```
if num %i = 0    
if isPrime(i) == True:
```

Also a logic error on

```
for i in range(-1, num, 2):
```

Complete code:

```
def is_prime(num):
  isPrime = True
  for i in range(-1, num, 2):
    if num % i = 0:
      isPrime = False
  return isPrime
def main():
  for i in range(1,101):
    if isPrime(i) == True:
      print(i,"is a prime number")
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `is_prime()` method instead of `isPrime` variable as it is a local variable to that method also there is some indentation problem. I am not sure which IDE you have been using I preferably use vscode as that has some useful extensions to handle these

[Playground](https://onlinegdb.com/B14PcQqVI)

```
def is_prime(num):
    isPrime = True
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num % i == 0:
            isPrime = False
    return isPrime

def main():
  for i in range(1,101):
    if is_prime(i) == True:
        print(i,"is a prime number")
main()
```